# Not getting desired output for Knapsack problem using greedy algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, data-structures, greedy

I'm trying to implement a greedy approach for the fractional knapsack problem.

The input format is: The first line of the input contains the number  of items and the capacity  of a knapsack.
The next  lines define the values and weights of the items. The -th line contains integers  and —the
value and the weight of -th item, respectively.

The output will be the maximum value.

I've implemented this algorithm in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

double get_optimal_value(int capacity, vector<int> weights, vector<int> values, int n) {
  double value = 0.0;
  double A[] {};
  int amt = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (capacity = 0){
      break;
    }
    else {
      amt = std::min(weights[i], capacity);
      weights[i] -= amt;
      A[i] = A[i] + amt;
      value = value + amt*(values[i]/weights[i]);
      capacity -= amt;
    }
  }
  return value;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  int capacity;
  std::cin >> n >> capacity;
  vector<int> values(n);
  vector<int> weights(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> values[i] >> weights[i];
  }

  double optimal_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values, n);

  std::cout.precision(10);
  std::cout << optimal_value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I'm inputting some values I'm getting output as 0

```
3 50
60 20
100 50
120 30
0
```

Any guidance on this will be very helpful. Thanking you in advance

Comment: Typo: `capacity = 0`. Your compiler should have warned you and using a debugger you could have noticed

Comment: Note that you are performing an integer division for update of `value`, I guess it is not what you want to do